# Angular reactive form phone number pattern validation

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have an add/edit reactive form with phone number input field. I have added a pipe that transforms the input from `9999999999` to `(999) 999-9999` and I am using a regex pattern to validate the same.

**HTML**

```
<input [value]="form.get('phone').value | phoneFormat" maxlength="14" formControlName="phone"/>
```

> phoneFormat is a pipe that converts the input value to desired format.

**Component**

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  phone: ['', [Validators.pattern(/((\(\d{3}\) ?)|(\d{3}-))?\d{3}-\d{4}/)]]
});
```

**Issues**

1. I have to transform the phone value to `9999999999` while saving the form.
2. While editing the form, the pattern validation fails initially because the phone number is not in desired format.

I am looking for a neat approach to handle this type of case.

Answer (score 1):

This validation is possible without using any pipe for conversion or transforming its value. By using `mask` validation of RxWeb.

The [@rxweb/reactive-form-validators](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rxweb/reactive-form-validators) has mask validation which can fulfill your validation requirement. It will validate your input as per the required regex format and save the value in its original form eg : 9999999999

```js
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
    userFormGroup: FormGroup

    constructor(
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.userFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
            phoneNumber:['', RxwebValidators.mask({mask:'(999)-999 9999' })], 
        });
    }

    onSubmit(){
      console.log(this.userFormGroup.value);
    }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form  [formGroup]="userFormGroup">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Phone Number</label>
      <input type="text" formControlName="phoneNumber" class="form-control"  />
     <small class="form-text text-danger" *ngIf="userFormGroup.controls.phoneNumber.errors">                     {{userFormGroup.controls.phoneNumber.errors.mask.message}}<br/></small>    
    </div>
    <button [disabled]="!userFormGroup.valid" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onSubmit()">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

For implementing this you need to import `RxReactiveFormsModule` in the main module and use `RxWebValidators` while formControl initialization.

Here is the stackblitz link of the above example :  [Open](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kfgvwj-acpg9e?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Answer (score 0):

why you change the form for saving?
just get the form value, assign it to an object and transform it as you want. but do not change the form value.

```
save() {
    let formValue = this.form.value;
    formValue.phoneNumber = formValue.phoneNumber.match(/(\d+)/);
    // rest of the job
}
```

and for the cases that you need to set form value (if it's a possible scenario) first normalize the phone number to the format that is valid then set the form value.

```
normalize(val) {
    let formValue = val;
    const phoneFormatPipe = new phoneFormat();
    formValue.phoneNumber = phoneFormatPipe.transform(formValue.phoneNumber);
    this.form.patchValue(formValue);
}
```

Comment: 1. I am just transforming the value before saving. The solution that I am looking for is to skip this transforming overhead.